# Selenium 4 EdgeDriver cannot run parallel tests under xUnit

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, xunit2

I have a console app which launches 2 Edge windows simultaneously and navigates within them just fine:

```
// usings
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;

// generic driver options
List<string> Options = new List<string>() {
    // "headless", // add this to run the browsers invisibly
    "no-sandbox",
    "incognito",
    "disable-gpu",
    "ignore-certificate-errors",
    "no-default-browser-check",
    "disable-web-security",
    "allow-insecure-localhost",
    "allow-running-insecure-content",
    "acceptInsecureCerts=true",
    "proxy-server='direct://'",
    "proxy-bypass-list=*",
    "disable-extensions",
    "disable-infobars",
    $"--window-size=1024,768",
};

// edge options 1
var options = new EdgeOptions();
options.LeaveBrowserRunning = false;
options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";

// add options 1 arguments
Options.ForEach(arg => { if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(arg)) options.AddArgument(arg); });

// Important: Define profile folder for first browser
options.AddArgument($@"--user-data-dir={Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\prof-1");

// edge options 2
var options2 = new EdgeOptions();
options2.LeaveBrowserRunning = false;
options2.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
options2.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";

// add options 1 arguments
Options.ForEach(arg => { if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(arg)) options2.AddArgument(arg); });

// Important: Define profile folder for second browser
options2.AddArgument($@"--user-data-dir={Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\prof-2");

// initialise driver service
using (var _service = OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"msedgedriver.exe"))
{
    _service.Start();

    // initialise first edge driver
    using (var driver = new EdgeDriver(_service, options))
    {
        // define short default wait times
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
        
        // send first browser window to a page
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");

        // initialise second edge driver
        using (var driver2 = new EdgeDriver(_service, options2))
        {
            // define short default wait times
            driver2.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            driver2.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
            driver2.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);

            // send second browswer window to a page
            driver2.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");

            // wait so the user can see what's happening
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            // stop browsers
            driver.Quit();
            driver2.Quit();
        }
    }
}

// using blocks will tidy up processes - check Task Manager for `Microsoft Edge WebDriver`
```

This listing is [here](https://gist.github.com/HoraceBury/cc27aeb23d6561b228cbeb7f179d0ec9).

The problem I have is that when I convert this to an xUnit test, when a second `EdgeDriver` is instantiated the driver instances fail to maintain a handle on the browser. I’ve implemented this as a test class base and a static class which provides the driver service and options object.

Static class:

```
private static List<string> Options => new List<string> {
            IsHeadless ? "headless" : "",
            "no-sandbox",
            "inprivate", // "incognito",
            "disable-gpu",
            "ignore-certificate-errors",
            "no-default-browser-check",
            "disable-web-security",
            "allow-insecure-localhost",
            "allow-running-insecure-content",
            "acceptInsecureCerts=true",
            "proxy-server='direct://'",
            "proxy-bypass-list=*",
            "disable-extensions",
            "disable-infobars",
            "remote-debugging-port=9222",
            $"--window-size={WindowSize}",
    };


public static EdgeOptions BrowserOptions
{
    get
    {
        lock (optionsLockObj)
        {
            var _options = new EdgeOptions();
            _options.LeaveBrowserRunning = false;
            _options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
            _options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";

            Options.ForEach(arg => { if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(arg)) _options.AddArgument(arg); });

            _options.AddArgument($@"--user-data-dir={Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\prof-{ProfileCounter++}");

            _options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Driver, LogLevel.Debug);

            return _options;
        }
    }
}

public static EdgeDriverService Service
{
    get
    {
        lock (serviceLockObj)
        {
            if (_service is null)
            {
                _service = OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"../../../driver/", @"msedgedriver.exe");
                _service.UseVerboseLogging = true;
                _service.Start();
            }
        }

        return _service;
    }
}
```

Base test class test method:

```
protected void TestBrowser(string testFilePath)
{
    var ops = TestEnvironment.BrowserOptions;
    var prof = ops.Arguments[ops.Arguments.Count-1];
    output.WriteLine($"--user-data-dir: {prof}");

    using (var driver = new EdgeDriver(TestEnvironment.Service, ops))
    {
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);

        try
        {
                        // do work
                    }
        finally
        {
            if (driver != null)
                driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

I have cut out a lot of stuff irrelevant to the question.

What I want to understand is why the xUnit created instances of the test classes (which all inherit the test class method above) would not be able to reference their relative `EdgeDriver` properly.

Answer (score 0):

try separatting drivers like this, and maybe if you want to do it more efficient do it with [threads](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/Threads-in-CSharp/).

Maybe You can not access the same driver at the same time in the same instance, so create a new one.

Try this:

```
// initialise driver service
using (var _service = OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"msedgedriver.exe"))
{
    _service.Start();

    // initialise first edge driver
    using (var driver = new EdgeDriver(_service, options))
    {
        // define short default wait times
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
        
        // send first browser window to a page
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");        
    }
}
// initialise second driver service separatelly
using (var _service2 = OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"msedgedriver.exe"))
{
    _service2.Start();

    // initialise second edge driver
    using (var driver = new EdgeDriver(_service2, options2))
    {
        // define short default wait times
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
        
        // send first browser window to a page
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");        
    }
}
```

Comment: My gist code proves that multiple instances of the same driver can be instantiated at the same time with a single service. What I don’t get is why, when running under xUnit, multiple threads (tasks) seem to be preventing my uniquely instantiated drivers from being referenced by the separate test classes.

Comment: Yes i understand but you are using the same resources of the driver, did you tried separatting it? kind regards

Comment: Do you mean creating separate services? I was under the impression that you only need one service to create all drivers.

Comment: Yes, like in the upper code